# How change Request Url in header by apache?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

Apache is using as proxy for jboss. It is redirecting all requests from 80 port to jboss-s ports. I added  https support of apache so all response to customer browser(JS, CSS etc) have has https links in header instead http.

Header example without ssl:

```
General
Request URL: http://www-prd.corp.sdl.com/ww/en/assets-re1/css/css.css
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Header with ssl include:

```
General
Request URL: https://www-prd.corp.sdl.com/ww/en/assets-re1/css/css.css
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

I want rewrite header which apache returned to browser as was - http:\URL .

I tried

```
 RewriteEngine  on
 Header edit request "^https://www-prd.corp.sdl.com/(.*)$" "http://www-prd.corp.sdl.com/$1"

 RewriteEngine  on
 Header edit "^https://www-prd.corp.sdl.com/(.*)$" "http://www-prd.corp.sdl.com/$1"
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www-prd.corp.sdl.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www-prd.corp.sdl.com$1 [L]
```

But these didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I used for changes by Substitute .